# Re sizing the box based on open layers 3 map zoom

Tags: openlayers-3

I am new to open layer 3 api's, I have a query : I have marked some locations and custom info window , which opens up on click of these markers. Please find fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/pe7hyr0x/13/)

```
var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([78, 21]),
    zoom: 2
}),
layers: [
new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
        layer: 'osm'
    })
})]
```

});

Is it possible do re-size the boxes when map is zommed in and out using mouse wheel. I plan to have many more cities marked , and boxes to be drawn on click of each marker and these boxes should be opened by default, so it would cover whole map . Can I change box size depending upon zoom level.
And also which layer to set to have map without any detailed information like airports , roads etc . I want map to have basic minimalist layer ,with country boundaries and city names only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the view `change:resolution` event and make the boxes bigger using the zoom level.  Here's an example:

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([78, 21])
});

var parentZoom = null;

view.on('change:resolution', function() {
    var zoom = view.getZoom();
    if (parentZoom !== null) {
        $('#zoom').text([
            'Parent zoom:',
            parentZoom,
            ', Current zoom:',
            zoom
        ].join(' '));
    }
    var width = 50 + (zoom * 10);
    var height = 30 + (zoom * 10);
    $('.mapDivs').width(width + 'px').height(height + 'px');
    parentZoom = zoom;
}, this);

view.setZoom(2);
```

See it live on JSFiddle (your example updated with the above code): http://jsfiddle.net/pe7hyr0x/15/

Comment: Thanks Alexandre , for your response. How to identify zoom-in / zoom-out events , because I need to reduce size while zoom-out and increase while zoom-in. Thanks

Comment: The above example already takes care of setting the size depending on the zoom level.  I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, but if the above doesn't do the trick for you you could keep a reference to the previous zoom level and compare on each resolution change.